# How to differentiate the fireauth login callback received for Login and signup

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am writing an angular application using firestore. 
I am calling Auth::createUserWithEmailAndPassword( to register a user
and also calling Auth::signInWithEmailAndPassword.

In both these cases the user gets logged in and the below subscription gets fired

```
this.afa.authState.subscribe( authState => {
      this.firebaseUser = authState;
      if (authState) {
        this.onLoginSuccessfulReceivedFromFirebase();
      } else {
        this.onLogout();
      }
      this.isLoggedIn = authState != null;
});
```

Is there a way for me to identify whether the callback got fired at automatic login during createUserWithEmailAndPassword or when specifically calling Auth::signInWithEmailAndPassword within the callback function

Comment: What is the operationType in the response for both cases?

Comment: What do you mean by operation type ?

Comment: Could you show authState value?

Answer (score 1):

You can look authUser metadata created timestamp and login timestamp property to understand when your user logged in to old account or when they created a account and get logged in.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to respond to account creation differently is by waiting for the promise of [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#create-user-with-email-and-password) to resolve.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(credential) {
  console.log(credential.user.uid);
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```